# German special characters (äÄöÖüÜß) are not encoded and converted to?

Tags: c#, .net, character-encoding, console-application

I am mentioning my problem in a simple test scenario. I am sending a message using a WebAPI.

Here is code:

```
string subject = "Test message for German special characters (äÄöÖüÜß)";
var utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
byte[] utfBytes = utf8.GetBytes(subject);
subject = utf8.GetString(utfBytes, 0, utfBytes.Length);

string aktz_sender = "test Absender";
string aktz_rec = "Test Empfänger";
string receiverIdent = "Test_Identity";
string att_type = "Test_Type";

string result = baseClass.SendMessage(subject, aktz_sender, aktz_rec, 
                                      receiverIdent, att_type, listOfAttachment);

if (result == "true")
    MessageBox.Show("Message send successfully");

listOfAttachment.Clear();
```

The message is sent successfully. But when the recipient receives the message in his inbox, the subject is shown as:

```
Test message for German special characters (???????)
```

i.e. each German special character is replaced by a `?` character. I have contacted with Web API vendor and got a reply that I have to make sure that each character is encoded in UTF-8 before sending the message, because the API is working entirely with UTF-8 encoding.

Please guide me where am I missing something.

Comment: Why are you converting a string into UTF-8 and then back again? Note that a string in .NET is *always* a sequence of UTF-16 code units. Under what circumstances would you expect `subject` not to be basically its original value? It sounds like the problem is probably in the `SendMessage` method that we can't see... it doesn't help that we've also no idea what this "WebAPI" is or how you're communicating with it.

Comment: `baseClass.SendMessage` - how does it send the message?

Comment: Maybe the send message doesn't use the write encoding,

Comment: What encoding is saved your source code?

Comment: @JonSkeet. thanks for your reply.